# Google maps JS API zoom in/out mouse scroll wheel without panning map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

When you zoom in/out with mouse  scroll wheel it pans the map in wired way that i don't like, is there option to disable panning this with google maps API?

I want map to zoom in/out with scroll wheel like when i press zoom in and out buttons on map interface (on center of map).

http://jsfiddle.net/4ozyvknr/

```
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8
  });
}
```

Comment: It just zooms in to where your mouse is, that's all. I don't find this to be *weird*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to prevent panning of map when zooming with mouse wheel.

Here's how i done it, note when you zoom in/out with mouse wheel map stay's centered at same coordinates regardless of cursor position.

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g49bsyr8/)

```js
function initMap() {
    var map_div = document.getElementById('map');

    map = new google.maps.Map(map_div, {
        center: {lat: 34.049388, lng: -118.259901},
        zoom: 10,
        scrollwheel: 0
    });
    
    map_div.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {

        if (event.deltaY && event.deltaY < 0) {
            //scroll up = zoom in;
            map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
        } else {
            //scroll down zoom out;
            map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
        }

        //disable scrolling of window
        event.preventDefault();

    });
    
}
```

```html
<div id="map" style="width:100%; height:200px;"></div>
<div style="height:300px;"></div>
<h1>End of Page</h1>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable zoom with scollwheel just add `scrollwheel: false`

```
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 8,
    scrollwheel: false
  });
}
```

EDIT: If you want to change the way it zooms with the scroll wheel, then have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752340/how-to-zoom-in-smoothly-on-a-marker-in-google-maps)

Comment: Not what i wanted see my answer